# How to release CGImageRef if required to return it?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, core-graphics

I have a method to resize a `CGImageRef` and return `CGImageRef`. The issue is the last few lines, where I need to somehow release but return it after. Any ideas? Thanks

```
 -(CGImageRef)resizeImage:(CGImageRef *)anImage width:(CGFloat)width height:(CGFloat)height
{

    CGImageRef imageRef = *anImage;

    CGImageAlphaInfo alphaInfo = CGImageGetAlphaInfo(imageRef);

    if (alphaInfo == kCGImageAlphaNone)
        alphaInfo = kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast;


    CGContextRef bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef), 4 * width, CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef), alphaInfo);

    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);

    CGImageRef ref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);

    CGContextRelease(bitmap);
    CGImageRelease(ref); //issue here

    return ref;

}
```

Comment: I believe in this case you should rename your method to include the word "new" or "copy", and then simply return it without releasing.  The caller will understand from the name that they own the object and they are responsible for releasing it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Cocoa memory management naming policy states, that you own an object that is created from methods whose name begin with *alloc*, *copy* or *new*.
This rules are also respected by the Clang Static Analyzer.

Note that there are slightly different conventions for Core Foundation. Details can be found in [Apple's Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html).

I modified your above method to conform to that naming conventions. I also removed the asterisk when passing in `anImage`, as `CGImageRef` is already a pointer. (Or was this on purpose?).
Note that you own the returned `CGImage` and have to `CGImageRelease` it later.

```
-(CGImageRef)newResizedImageWithImage:(CGImageRef)anImage width:(CGFloat)width height:(CGFloat)height
{
    CGImageAlphaInfo alphaInfo = CGImageGetAlphaInfo(anImage);
    if (alphaInfo == kCGImageAlphaNone)
    {
        alphaInfo = kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast;
    }
    CGContextRef bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(anImage), 4 * width, CGImageGetColorSpace(anImage), alphaInfo);
    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), anImage);
    CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
    CGContextRelease(bitmap);
    return image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also operate on the pointer `anImage` (after removing the asterisk, like @weichsel suggested) and return `void`.

Still, you should read your code and think about the questions:

- Who owns `anImage`? (clearly not your method, as it does neither retain nor copy it)
- What happens if it is released by the owner while you're in your method? (or other things that might happen to it while your code runs)
- What happens to it after your method finishes? (aka: did you remember to release it in the calling code)

So, I would strongly encourage you not to mix CoreFoundation, which works with functions, pointers and "classic" data-structures, and Foundation, which works with objects and messages.
If you want to operate on CF-structures, you should write a C-function which does it. If you want to operate on Foundation-objects, you should write (sub-)classes with methods. If you want to mix both or provide a bridge, you should know exactly what you are doing and write wrapper-classes which expose a Foundation-API and handle all the CF-stuff internally (thus leaving it to you when to release structures).